# Based on VS based off of

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

I have used “based on” for the entirety of my life until I went to a UK boarding school where 90% of the time I hear my teachers say “based off of” instead.

For example, ”We will give you your final grades **based off of** your performance over the past 2 years.”

I happen to have an English tutor and I asked him what’s the difference, then he said he hasn’t heard of based followed by “off of” as an alternative to saying “based on”, all his life. He then remarked “based off of” as rubbish and advised me not to use it. Now I am even more confused. Would you guys use “based on” or “based off of”?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: As I speak British English, I would only say "based on" (or "based upon"). I see "off of" as non-standard. However, American English speakers might see it as entirely acceptable.

Comment: @Greybeard I am an American English speaker, and I would say exactly what you would say. I would never say *based off of*.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot tell you what the difference is but I can tell you this:

Based off of is less formal but is used more often in convesation

Based on has been in use for centuries yet based off of is more recently popular

Based on is generally favored as gramatically correct but is not seen as straightforward as someting like would of vs would have

Answer (score 0):

I see no reason for saying 'based off, whereas 'based on' has been standard usage for what seems forever. To use a base, you have to add to it; 'Based off of' does not do this, so it is a mere affectation.
Unfortunately all the dictionaries and word books I have consulted do not mention either usage!

Answer (score -1):

Consider where an object is placed in relation to its base. A base is a foundation or a support for something which sits on it.

"Based off" makes no sense at all.

Comment: Your logic seems sound, but we rely on a non-subjective element in answers as much as possible, thus: your answer would benefit from linked references to support your claim.

Comment: I guess as country of birth, residence and historical background "might" come into play in the comments, it'd be pretty interesting to see that indicated in the answers. 

As there's been a hockey stick effect in frequency in written text in recent times, I guess it's got to have some explanation. 

Perhaps it is a typical American variant, or is it that it's been introduced by non native speakers writing eg academic text? It seems generally (to me as a non-native speaker) that Americans are more tolerant to try out new usages, perhaps as they are a larger and more heterogenous "group"?